# Version of css overwrite

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and when I am inspecting an element .box, I saw it has two same css class that one of it overwrite another.

```
  .box { //theme.css:182
     background-color: green;
  }

  .box { //theme.css:1029
     background-color: red;
  }
```

when I go to the actual css I only saw one background-color:red; but can not find the other. Do you have any idea where did it come from?

Comment: please put in your html , css code

Comment: Open your css file using notepad, Press Ctrl + F and type .box

Comment: Sometimes that happens in themes, when html has a few linked css files with the same name but different paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the inspect element developers tool in your browser is seeing two `backgrounds` for `.box` then there are two backgrounds in your code.

Try opening your code editor and press `ctrl f` then use the search tool to search for all `.box`. You probably have given your `.box` two `background` colors or have write the `.box` twice or have given an `inline style` to `box` in your `html code` or you've linked multiple `css` files to your `html` that has the `.box` with different `background properties`.

Please check all this.